# Merging Table Header Cells Using tableGrob

Tags: r, merge, gridextra

I am currently creating a table image using:

```
SummaryTable <- data.frame(
  index,

  xa,
  xb,

  ya,
  yb,

  za,
  zb

)
names(SummaryTable) <- c("Index",
                         "Main X Sub A",
                         "Main X Sub B",
                         "Main Y Sub A",
                         "Main Y Sub B",
                         "Main Z Sub A",
                         "Main Z Sub B")

tt <- ttheme_default(colhead=list(fg_params = list(parse=TRUE)))
tbl <- tableGrob(SummaryTable, rows=NULL, theme=tt)

grid.arrange(tbl,as.table=TRUE)
```

With output:
[image]

Using dput( SummaryTable ):

```
structure(list(Index = 0:8, `Main X Sub A` = c(1, 0.69, 0.61, 
0.56, 0.5, 0.44, 0.4, 0.36, 0.33), `Main X Sub B` = c(0.86, 0.62, 
0.51, 0.42, 0.36, 0.31, 0.27, 0.24, 0.23), `Main Y Sub A` = c(1, 
0.8, 0.74, 0.68, 0.63, 0.56, 0.52, 0.47, 0.43), `Main Y Sub B` = c(0.86, 
0.77, 0.67, 0.59, 0.53, 0.47, 0.43, 0.39, 0.36), `Main Z Sub A` = c(0, 
0.17, 0.23, 0.27, 0.33, 0.37, 0.42, 0.46, 0.49), `Main Z Sub B` = c(0, 
0.24, 0.33, 0.42, 0.48, 0.55, 0.6, 0.64, 0.66)), .Names = c("Index", 
"Main X Sub A", "Main X Sub B", "Main Y Sub A", "Main Y Sub B", 
"Main Z Sub A", "Main Z Sub B"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

However, I would like to merge the top headers to achieve this output (as png or pdf):

[image]

This table was created in Excel. X, Y and Z are within merged cells.

Is anyone able to assist with methods on merging cells?

Comment: Please `dput( SummaryTable )`. PNGs are useless.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way would be to use `combine` ([described here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/tableGrob.html)), to add an additional header row to your table.

Using an idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32173928/r-tablegrob-change-format-of-row) you can create a `tableGrob` for the additional header row.

You can then alter the `l`, and `r` of the `gtable` to correct the positioning.

```
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

# example data & header row
tab <- tableGrob(mtcars[1:3, 1:4], rows=NULL)
header <- tableGrob(mtcars[1, 1:2], rows=NULL, cols=c("head1", "head2")) 

jn <- gtable_combine(header[1,], tab, along=2)
jn$widths <- rep(max(jn$widths), length(jn$widths)) # make column widths equal
#grid.newpage()
#grid.draw(jn) # see what it looks like before altering gtable

# change the relevant rows of gtable
jn$layout[1:4 , c("l", "r")] <- list(c(1, 3), c(2, 4))

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(jn)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @user20650

I am attempting this for my table using this code:

`tab <- tableGrob(SummaryTable[1:9, 2:7], rows=NULL)
header <- tableGrob(SummaryTable[1, 1:3], rows=NULL, cols=c("head1", "head2", "head3")) 
jn <- join(header[1,], tab, along=2)
jn$widths <- rep(max(jn$widths), length(jn$widths))
jn$layout[1:7 , c("l","r")] <- list(c(1, 3),c(2, 5),c(4, 7))`

Here is my result, with the headers not merging.

http://i.imgur.com/89UNHt2.png

Comment: Almost there... try `jn$layout[1:6 , c("l","r")] <- list(c(1, 3, 5),c(2, 4, 6))`.  Its worth looking at `jn$layout[1:6 , ]` before and after the changes to see that they make sense) This uses vector recycling, so that the `l`eft column is `1,3,5,1,3,5` and the `r`ight `2,4,6,2,4,6`