# Creating a row for table name

Tags: r

I have a table as such:

```
    +-----------+----------------+----------+  
    |           |     Type 1     | Type 2   |
    +-----------+----------------+----------+     
    |    Mean   |     31,2       |    16,0  |
    |   Median  |     51,3       |    16,0  |
    |    Max    |     40,4       |    6,0   |
    |    Min    |     100,0      |    16,0  |
    |    Q1     |     34,6       |    16,0  |
    |    Q3     |     16,0       |    16,0  |
    +---+------------+-----------+----------+
```

How can I add a title to it, so it becomes:

```
    +-----------+----------------+----------+  
    |        INSERT TABLE TITLE HERE        |   
    +-----------+----------------+----------+  
    |           |     Type 1     | Type 2   |
    +-----------+----------------+----------+     
    |    Mean   |     31,2       |    16,0  |
    |   Median  |     51,3       |    16,0  |
    |    Max    |     40,4       |    6,0   |
    |    Min    |     100,0      |    16,0  |
    |    Q1     |     34,6       |    16,0  |
    |    Q3     |     16,0       |    16,0  |
    +---+------------+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: r is not excel...

Comment: Could you explain your situation.. I mean.. just a bit more?

Comment: For making tables to output into documents, take a look at `knitr` package's `kable` function or `xtable` package for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about output tables for LaTeX, HTML or Word, then you want to use a package for that purpose. There's a list of possible packages [here](https://hughjonesd.github.io/huxtable/design-principles.html). (Disclaimer: I wrote `huxtable`, which is one of the options.) Or you could just use `knitr`'s built in `kable`.

In `huxtable`, here's how to do it:

```
library(huxtable)
# sample data:
tbl <- table(sample(letters[1:5], 20, replace = TRUE), 
      sample(LETTERS[11:15], 20, replace = TRUE))
huxtbl <- as_hux(tbl, add_rownames = FALSE)
huxtbl <- rbind(rep('', 5), huxtbl)
colspan(huxtbl)[1, 1] <- 5
huxtbl[1, 1] <- 'Table title goes here'
huxtbl
```

Which produces something like:

```
  V1   V2   V3   V4   V5   
   Table title goes here    
   K    L    M    N    O    
   0    0    1    1    1    
   0    1    3    1    0    
   1    0    2    0    0    
   1    2    1    1    1    
   0    1    0    2    0
```

on-screen, and exports the table to markdown, HTML or LaTeX.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `tableGrob` from package `gridExtra`
check this post : 
[Merging Table Header Cells Using tableGrob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33214671/merging-table-header-cells-using-tablegrob)